# How do we calculate $\int\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$?

Tags: integration

How do we calculate:

$$I=\int\dfrac{\ln(\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$$

I'm stuck, please help.
I tried to use the substitution $y=\cos x$, so I got:
$$I=\int\dfrac{\ln(y)}{x^2-1}dx$$ this is where I got stuck.

Comment: If you dont show some work,  your question will be closed.

Comment: @Ali Shather – What do you mean?

Comment: Like show what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: As long as you show any kind of work , they have no excuse/right to close your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks! @Ali Shather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integration by parts we have

$$\int\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\ dx=\frac12\ln x[\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)]-\frac12\int\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx$$

$$=\frac12\ln x[\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)]+\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$$

Note that $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=-\int\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Recall that $\sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2x$. So,
$$\int\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\sin x}\,\mathrm dx \equiv \int \sin x\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx = -\int\sin x\cdot\dfrac{\ln(\cos x)}{\cos^2x - 1}\,\mathrm dx$$

Now, let $u = \cos x\implies \mathrm dx = -\dfrac1{\sin x}\,\mathrm du$.

$$-\int\sin x\cdot\dfrac{\ln(\cos x)}{\cos^2x - 1}\,\mathrm dx \equiv \int\frac{\ln u}{u^2 - 1}\,\mathrm du$$

Notice that the result is in the form of dilogarithms $(Li_2)$.